# How long will leafhoppers stay after grapes are removed?

Tags: pests, grape-vine

We have grapes that have sadly been overwhelmed with leafhoppers, which totally decimate the appearance of the leaves, to the point of white chlorosis. Control methods have proven only temporarily effective, and a lot of work. We're planning to cut them down (before the plants return from dormancy), but I'm wondering, how long would we have to be without grapes before the leafhoppers moved somewhere else? Would they stick around the yard longer than a year even without grapes? (Assuming the grape vines are completely removed, and then new ones are replanted after the waiting period.)

Here's a picture of the leafhoppers, taken in the 2015 season before they did much foliar damage:

[image: Leafhoppers from 2015 in southwestern Idaho]

Here's an example of damage to the leaves (although it can get to the point where you don't really see much, if any, natural green on many, if any of the leaves):

[image: Leafhopper damage to grape foliage in southwestern Idaho in 2015.]

Note that I'm not particularly looking for methods of controlling leafhoppers (although you're welcome to mention them, too). I'm just wondering how long these leafhoppers will stick around in an area after the grapes are gone (i.e. how many years, if more than one).

Update (30 June 2018): We kept our grapes, but we got rid of the trees that shaded them (and all of our other trees). Earlier, before the trees were gone, this year, we had some leafhoppers and leafhopper damage, but now I don't see any foliar damage, except on the old growth that is shaded by the new growth. I guess they don't like vines in full sun as much (or maybe their predators like the sun more). The leafhoppers seem to be gone (I don't see any, even on the old, shaded growth).

Comment: Yes, they will, they can overwinter on surrounding plants, but where are you and which particular variety of leafhopper were they? Some reading here  which may help http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r302300111.html

Comment: I'm in southwestern Idaho. It's an awesome-looking variegated type, with darker dark colors than most I see online, including than the grape leafhopper. I'll have to find the pictures I took of them in the summer. We had a cold winter (it got to -21° F.), but we had a lot of snow that might have insulated the ground, too. The grapes are dormant,  now.

Comment: The leafhoppers have been around for a few years (I'd never seen them as a grape pest before that), and we've had warm winters for the last few years, too, until this last one. We still get some grapes, but we haven't had lots, lately.

Comment: @Bamboo I added an image.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to cut your vines right down to the ground and keep them at ground level, not allowing them to grow for a year, then the leafhoppers might go, but its unlikely - the image you've shown is not grape leafhopper, but some other type of leafhopper, and those may stay in your garden on other plants because they're not dependent on your grapevines.

Answer (score 1):

Usually leafhoppers are not a huge problem, so I expect that some predators will start to kill them soon.

But birds are also a problem, so on some places people put nets around grapes, or around the whole plants. I think you can use nets also to block most of damages.

Additionally, I would check online more about *your* species of grasshoppers, to understand better they biology.  When they eat your grapes, they are already adult (and maybe also the second generation).  Try to understand where the younger generation are living, and try to combat them earlier.